# Ubuntu Doesn't Recognize My Samsung SCH-R580 Phone in USB

Tags: usb, samsung, phone

I plug my Samsung SCH-R580 cellphone with a micro sd card into my Ubuntu 12.10 desktop computer and the computer doesn't even know that it's connected. The phone says "Connected to PC" but not the PC. And I don't have a micro SD card adapter. I want to be able to put files onto my phone and take files off of it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

My brother has that same phone but the 680 version of it. I believe it uses a MTP transfer method, which unfortunately doesn't work with any of the MTP software I tested in the software center. For my Nexus 7 I use the gMTP program and it works great. THAT IS THE ONLY ANDROID SERIES I have ever seen that doesn't work on Ubuntu to be honest.